# Passing to limit to obtain an identity (explain a text please)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $P:H \to K$ be a nonlinear map, where $K$ is a closed convex subset of $H$ which is a Hilbert space. We know that $P$ is Lipschitz with a Lipschitz constant one.

Let $S \subset H$ be a set. We know that for every $s \in S$,

$$P(s+th) -Ps = th$$
holds, for some fixed $h \in H$, as long as $t$ is small enough (it depends on $s$).

Let $\bar S$ denote the closure of $S$. Then apparently, due to density and Lipschitzness of $P$, we have that for every $s \in \bar S$,
$$P(s+th) -Ps = th + o(t)$$
where $t^{-1}o(t) \to 0$ as $t \to 0$.

Could somebody tell me how this is gotten, and how to describe $o(t)$ precisely?

This is Lemma 1 on page 620 of this paper https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jmsj/1240432858.

Comment: Your question does not seem to properly reflect the cited lemma: $o$ is not a function, but rather the ["little-o" notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) used in expressing asymptotics, therefore the formula $t^{-1}o(t) \to 0$ is not clear to me (and I also don't find it in the original text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the lemma wrong. The closure is not for $S$ but for the set of
directions $h\in H$.

Given $\varepsilon>0$ for $h\in\overline{H}$ there exists $h_{\varepsilon}\in
H$ such that $\Vert h-h_{\varepsilon}\Vert\leq\varepsilon$. Then
\begin{align*}
\Vert P(s+th)-P(s)-th\Vert & \leq\Vert P(s+th)-P(s+th_{\varepsilon})\Vert\\
& +\Vert P(s+th_{\varepsilon})-P(s)-th_{\varepsilon}\Vert+\Vert
th_{\varepsilon}-th\Vert\\
& \leq\text{Lip }P\Vert s+th-(s+th_{\varepsilon})\Vert+0+|t|\Vert
h_{\varepsilon}-h\Vert\\
& \leq\text{Lip }P|t|\Vert h-h_{\varepsilon}\Vert+0+|t|\Vert h_{\varepsilon
}-h\Vert\leq(\text{Lip }P+1)\varepsilon|t|,
\end{align*}
and so
$$
\left\Vert \frac{P(s+th)-P(s)}{t}-h\right\Vert \leq(\text{Lip }P+1)\varepsilon
,
$$
which shows that
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{P(s+th)-P(s)}{t}-h=0.
$$

Comment: you used that $P(s+th_\epsilon) = P(s) + th_\epsilon$ but this is true only for small $t$, i.e. for $t \leq T_\epsilon$. So maybe more care is needed in the passing to the limit.

Comment: well, since this holds for $|t|\le T_\varepsilon$, from the inequality 
$$
\left\Vert \frac{P(s+th)-P(s)}{t}-h\right\Vert \leq(\text{Lip }P+1)\varepsilon
$$ you get 
$$\limsup_{t\to 0}
\left\Vert \frac{P(s+th)-P(s)}{t}-h\right\Vert \leq(\text{Lip }P+1)\varepsilon
$$ and then you let $\varepsilon \to 0$.